# Deleted photos show up in recyclerview

Tags: android

Using the code below, I was able to show (assumed to be) deleted photos in a recyclerview.

```
public ArrayList<File> listf(File xfile, ArrayList<File> files) {


    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = xfile.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            files.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file, files);
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

where the File was:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

and the ArrayList was:

```
new ArrayList<File>
```

I was expecting to see the 12 pictures that can be seen in the gallery app, but I saw pictures that were deleted months ago (in addition to the pictures that could be seen in the gallery app). I also saw thumbnails for deleted videos.  My current understanding of how computers delete files is that the OS marks the files as deleted and finally overwrites them when space is needed for new files. However, that doesn't seem like a reasonable explanation considering the number of video clips I've recorded and then deleted over the course of months  (some of which can be as big as 3 GB). Can someone explain to me how android deletes files (or provide a reference for me to read through, I been looking for hours on google and S/O and haven't found anything useful)?

Comment: When you use `adb shell`, or use Device File Explorer in Android Studio, to look at `/sdcard/DCIM/` or `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/`, do you see these files?

Comment: I see /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/

Comment: And, inside there, do you see the files that you are referring to in your question? Your code is doing a recursive traversal of this directory's contents, according to your question.

Comment: when I look into the file manager on my phone, I only see the 12 pictures I mentioned in the question. There are other subfolders that show up as containing zero files. When connecting the phone to the computer I see the same thing within the DCIM directory, 12 pics.

Comment: "when I look into the file manager on my phone" -- please use `adb shell` or the Device File Explorer in Android Studio. In addition, you might log the paths of the files that your code is encountering.

Comment: When using Device File Explorer, I found the desired files under /sdcard/DCIM instead of /storage/emulated/0/DCIM. I'm guessing I should switch out the paths and see what happens....

Comment: I'm still seeing a lot of old pictures

Comment: The folder with all the old thumbnails is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails

Comment: All the movie thumbnails are removed, I added an extra conditional so that none of the files from that folder when be read into memory. Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convention, in macOS, Linux, Android, and some other operating systems, is for certain types of apps to ignore directories with a leading `.`. Your file manager is doing this. The `MediaStore` — which your gallery most likely is using — is doing this. Your code is not. Nor does `adb shell` or the Device File Explorer, which is why I recommended that you use those tools.

In general, the right way to get the roster of images on the device is to query the `MediaStore`.

But, if you want to stick with your existing code, your options are:

- Live with the results, or
- Add in smarts to see if the directory name starts with `.` and, if it does, skip it

Comment: I had already added to conditional to remove the thumbnails, but I'll look into this MediaStore.